# Правильна ли фраза: "рыбалка форели и осетра"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Кусочек из рекламного листка:
***Рыбалка форели и осетра***  на берегу Наровы "у Ивана"
Запуталась, не могу решить: можно ли так сказать, правильно ли? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Никак нет. Ловля форели и осетра. Промысел, добыча.

Comment: Это не промысел и не добыча. Это место отдыха - "у Ивана",  - где за денежку можно "поналовить" рыбки,  и "поприготовить" ее тут же.

Comment: Правый берег Наровы(Нарвы) - российский, левый - эстонский. Иван, владелец хутора Lepa, организовал у себя выращивание, вылов - продажу и приготовление рыбы, баню, места для шашлыков и детских игр. А вот купаться в реке официально запрещено: граница.

Answer (score 3):

Про "рыбалка (кого)" уже сказали.
С точки зрения нормы "рыбалка на" - тоже не вариант. Я бы счел это неким профессионализмом, но профессионалы говорят "рыбная ловля", "рыбный промысел", а любители на щуку или там сазана - *ходят*. "Рыбалка на форель" - косноязычие, хотя, увы и встречается достаточно часто.

Лучше все-таки "ловля", пугаться тут нечего: у Сабанеева слово "рыбалка" встречается раза три - все в отвлеченном значении, как некое занятие, а не сам процесс..

Если нужно сохранить слово "рыбалка", то только в варианте а) ***"форелевая или осетровая рыбалка"***, б) ***рыбалка: форель и осетр***.

ЗЫ. Реклама странная, в РФ вылов осетра запрещен полностью. Хотя браконьерствуют, увы безбожно. Но чтоб рекламу браконьерам создавать...

Comment: Товарищ @Мимоходов, вы бы ещё на Карамзина сослались. Чего там Сабанеев?! Профессионалы говорят "рыбная ловля"? Вот это да... ЗЫ. И вообще, вы не в курсе, тов.Мимоходов: выращивают осетров, запускают в маленький прудик, а потом приглашают рыболовов, что полностью разрешено.

Comment: Так это они в Эстонии. Браконьерствуют.

Comment: @IrinaGL Ясно, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ни "рыбалка форели", ни "рыбалка на форель" не говорят (не путать с охотой на кабана!)

Comment: Не говорят, но пишут? ))))

Comment: Вырубать топором! )

Answer (score 0):

Слово "**рыбалка**" характеризует способ времяпровождения, при котором занимаются ловлей рыбы. Напрямую с видом рыбы это слово грамматически не связывается, но оно очень выразительно, даёт хорошее представление о том, чем будут заняты потенциальные клиенты. Чтобы не отказываться от употребления слова, можно поступить напр. так:

> "У Ивана": рыбалка на берегу Наровы, с выловом [ловлей, отловом] форели и осетра.

**P.S.** При выборе для рекламного материала конкретного слова, обозначающего  саму "ловлю", нужно считаться с тем, что "отлов" звучит несколько формально, а "ловля" не означает результативности, указывая лишь на процесс, занятие.

Comment: *С выловом, с ловлей, с отловом*... Нда уж. ((

Comment: *У Ивана": рыбалка на берегу Наровы, с выловом [ловлей, отловом] форели и осетра.* - у меня только одно сомнение, это слишком литературно. Реклама требует немного другого стиля.

Comment: Возможно, это не рекламный слоган, а пункт из проспекта многопрофильных посредников. Для слогана нужно что-нибудь вроде: " у нас клюют осетры и форель!"